# How can I set my CheckBoxes inside of my ListBox to be disabled

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, checkbox, listbox

How can I set my CheckBoxes inside of my ListBox to be disabled?

XAML:

```
<GroupBox Header="A GroupBox" BorderThickness="2" Width="247" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="183" Margin="405,155,0,0">
    <Grid>
        <ListBox Name="MyListBoxThing" ItemsSource="{Binding MyItemsClassThing}" Height="151" Width="215" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"  ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Margin="10,0,0,0">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <CheckBox  IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}"  />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
</GroupBox>
```

Mainwindow.xaml.cs

```
public class MyItemsClassThing
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
}
```

> The Problem: I'm trying to disable my CheckBox's **dynamically** that are inside of my listbox. But when I disable the ListBox it also disables my vertical scroll bar. So now I'm thinking that I should access the CheckBoxes inside of the Listbox inside of my GroupBox and then disable them one by one. How can I do this?

I tried this, but had no luck:

```
var children = LogicalTreeHelper.GetChildren(MyListBoxThing);
foreach(var item in children)
{
    var c = item as CheckBox;
    c.IsEnabled = false;
}
```

I want to say like:

```
loop through the listbox
   if you find a check box
       checkbox.isenabled = false
   endif
end
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try to bind the IsEnabled property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add an `IsEnabled` property to your `MyItemsClassThing` and implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface:

```
public class MyItemsClassThing : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }

    private bool _isEnabled = true;
    public bool IsEnabled
    {
        get { return _isEnabled; }
        set { _isEnabled = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

And bind the `IsEnabled` property of the `CheckBox` to this property:

```
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" IsEnabled="{Binding IsEnabled}"  />
```

You can the simply set the `IsEnabled` property of the `MyItemsClassThing` objects in your source collection to disable the `Checkbox`:

```
foreach(var item in MyListBoxThing.Items.OfType<MyItemsClassThing>())
{
    item.IsEnabled = false;
}
```

Comment: How exactly do you set the MyItemsClassThing ItemsSource collection then? This is supposed to be an IEnumerable<MyItemsClassThing>. Then it should work provided that you have implemented the INotifyPropertyChanged correctly. Please post your full code.

Comment: It seems I made a human error in mimicking your code. I got it to work. Thank you for the brilliant solution! Much appreciated my friend! This really helped!!

Comment: I apparently accidently downvoted it a couple days ago (because I didnt think it worked due to my own error) would you mind editing and putting like a period somewhere or something so that it will think it has been "edited" and will allow me to upvote this awesome answer?